# what is difference between "if (systemReady == false) return;" and "if (!systemReady) return;" in cpu

Tags: objective-c

what is difference between

if (systemReady == false) return;

and

if (!systemReady) return;

in cpu?

Comment: I would tag differently, but I'm not sure what to tag with.

Comment: Most programming languages (and I'd be surprised if objective-c is an exception) is defined in terms of abstract semantics. That is, the spec says what *should* happen, now *how* it should happen. There are most likely several valid ways of compiling those two snippets of code (especially when you take multiple different architectures into account), so it's not possible to tell what the difference is on a cpu level. If I was forced to guess, I'd say that the machine code generated is equivalent for the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you check it with your debugger? Okay, there is little reason to do so. And, to be honest, there is little reason to answer to your Q. However, …

The expression `!expr` will compile to something like this: (depends on the CPU)

```
Load expr
Complement
Branch if zero
```

The expression `expr==false` will compile top something like this:

```
Load expr
(Compare with #0)
Branch if (not) zero
```

If there is a difference in execution time, the compiler will automatically chose the faster one, if you set the optimization level to something higher than no optimization.

So simply do not care about this. Chose the option, you think that it is better to read.

Answer (score 1):

With any half-way decent compiler, those statements will compile to equivalent machine code. Even if they didn't, though, the difference would be so slight that you'd have to be insane to care. Do not prematurely optimize. Also, choice of algorithms is almost always going to swamp implementation details in determining performance by several orders of magnitude.

Finally, you should never compare against `true`, `false`, `YES`, `NO`, etc. It's dangerous because there are true values which are not equal to `true`. Any non-zero value is true.

It's also bad style. `systemReady` is (apparently) already a boolean. There's no need to compare it to anything to make it a boolean.

Ask yourself, would you ever write:

```
if ((systemReady == false) == true) return;
```

Or:

```
if (((systemReady == false) == true) == true) return;
```

?

If not, then you should realize why writing `if (systemReady == false) ...` is wrong, too. It is similarly adding a redundant comparison for no reason.

So, use your second form: `if (!systemReady) ...`.

Comment: `expr == true` is redundant (for a boolean expr), `expo == false` is not redundant as `!expr` is not. Moreover, there is nothing wrong with comparing with boolean values as there is nothing wrong with integer compares to integer literals.